# Using EPPlus for Excel, how to set focus on a cell in the active sheet?

Tags: excel, select, epplus, worksheet, setfocus

I can set an active worksheet using the 
Package.Workbook.View.ActiveTab = iSheetNumber;
Now I want to set focus on cell A1, so when excel file is opened in excel I want to see that cell A1 is selected.
How do I achieve that using EPPlus for Excel ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
worksheet.Select(cellAddress)
```

works for me.
In your case:

```
worksheet.Select("A1");
```

Comment: It does select the A1 cell from the worksheet, but the horizontal scroll does not move to extreme left. I want to be able to view it, right now its off the screen. I have attached a screenshot in main description.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to set the view when opening the document is to manually edit the xml.

```
string cellAddress = $"A1"; 
worksheet.Select(cellAddress);
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = worksheet.WorksheetXml;
System.Xml.XmlNodeList elements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("sheetView");
if(elements != null && elements.Count == 1)
{
  foreach(System.Xml.XmlNode node in elements[0].ChildNodes)
  {
     if(node.Name == "pane")
     {
       if(node.Attributes != null)
       {
          foreach(System.Xml.XmlAttribute att in node.Attributes)
          {
             if(att.Name == "topLeftCell")
             { 
                att.Value = cellAddress;
             }
          }
       }
    }   
  }
}
```