# Select doesn't scroll to the focused cell by default

Tags: .net, excel, epplus

I have been building an `.xlsx` Excel file using EPPlus and I'm trying to set the default scroll position to a cell on the far right so it can be visible to the user when they open the Excel file for the first time.

I've tried [focusing the target cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555240/using-epplus-for-excel-how-to-set-focus-on-a-cell-in-the-active-sheet) using EPPlus [`worksheet.Select(cellAddress)`](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.1/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelWorksheet_Select_System_String_), but while the cell is selected, the scroll position still remains at the very left.

Is there a way to set the default scroll position to a cell?

Comment: You should be building an .xlsm file, not an .xlsx.

Comment: Are there any advantages to using .xlsm? There is no macro and most of our company's Excel files are .xlsx, I'm hesitant to introduce inconsistency by using a different format.

Comment: "worksheet.Select(cellAddress)" is VB code, so you need to use an xlsm file.

Comment: Oh I'm using the .NET library EPPlus's [worksheet.Select(cellAddress)](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.1/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelWorksheet_Select_System_String_). The code is not in VB. Let me update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default scroll position to a cell address is set separately by [ExcelWorksheetView.TopLeftCell](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.1/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheetView.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelWorksheetView_TopLeftCell). (By default its value is an empty string `""`, which means `A1`.)

For example, to make the 50th column of the 1st row be at the top left of the view, use the following:

```
worksheet.View.TopLeftCell = ws.Cells[1, 50].Address;

/* Or simply */
worksheet.View.TopLeftCell = "AX";
```